# Zend Properl filterBy with collate

Tags: php, zend-framework, propel

I'm new with propel and I have one question. How I can put into filterBy collation?
I need something like this:

```
SELECT id, name, email FROM users WHERE email COLLATE utf8_bin = "teSt@domain.com"
```

I need case-sensitivity search, but I can't change table schema for now.
I'm trying:

```
$model = Model_Propel_Users::create()->filterByName('COLLATE utf8_bin ' . $name)
```

But it doesn't work.
Anyone have ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution, perhaps it will be usefull for somebody.

First, I've added new method into model:

```
public function findUser($email)
{
    $criteria = new Criteria();

    $conn = Propel::getConnection();
    $cq = Model_Propel_Users::EMAIL . ' COLLATE utf8_bin LIKE ' . $conn->quote($email);
    $criteria->add(null, $cq, Criteria::CUSTOM);
    $user = Model_Propel_Users::doSelectOne($criteria);
    return $user;
}
```

Then just make call to get result:

```
$user = Model_Propel_Users::create()->findUser($email);
```